# Сохранение логов после перезагрузки системы

Tags: linux, логирование

Есть приложение на с++, которое пишет данные в лог.

Используется `syslog(LOG_INFO,"Init")`, к примеру. Данные записываются в `/var/log/messages`.

При перезагрузке системы данные из `/var/log/messages` удаляются. 
Есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы логи не удалялись? Предполагаю, что нужно использовать `syslog.conf`.

Как можно решить проблему?

Операционная система: *busybox/linux*.

Comment: Вариант "записывать в другой файл" не рассматривается?

Comment: логи удаляются при перезагрузке? Ерунда какая-то. Смотрите конфиг logrotate (в центос /etc/logrotate.conf) Может там стоит правило удаления логов

Comment: @LEQADA нет нужен именно этот

Answer (score 5, accepted):

это, вероятно, т.н. «embedded»-система. и каталог `/var` (или только `/var/log`) находится на временной файловой системе (скорее всего, типа *tmpfs*), которая расположена в оперативной памяти, и создаётся при загрузке системы.

пример проверки (это дистрибутив *openwrt*):

```
$ df /var
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                    63268       380     62888   1% /tmp
$ ls -ld /var
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             4 Sep 17  2013 /var -> /tmp
```

делается это с целью сохранения ресурса накопителя информации, который в таких устройствах обычно может выдержать довольно ограниченное количество операций записи.

---

не зная подробностей об используемом вами дистрибутиве, могу предположить лишь такие общие варианты решения:

- изменить вашу программу, чтобы она писала данные в файл, расположенный на блочном устройстве хранения информации;
- изменить систему инициализации вашего дистрибутива так, чтобы каталог `/var` или `/var/log` или хотя бы файл `/var/log/messages` располагался не в памяти, а на блочном устройстве;
- изменить конфигурацию используемого вами системного логгера так, чтобы он записывал не в файл `/var/log/messages`, а в файл, расположенный на блочном устройстве. или, например, отсылал логируемую информацию по сети на другой компьютер.

Comment: во временной файловой системе его нет, находится на блочном устройстве.

Comment: что выдаёт команда `df /var/log/messages`?

Comment: Уже разобрался. Действительно Вы были, файлы находились во временной файловой системе. Спасибо!

Comment: Можно ли сделать отдельный лог файл для приложения?

Comment: @Sebefour, я думаю, лучше задать по этому поводу новый вопрос. с подробным изложением того, что именно вами используется: как минмум — какой версии и какой дистрибутив, какой системный логгер.